# Change the amount of tick labels on the x axis shown?

Tags: d3.js

I would like to change the number of tick labels on the x axis. I'm not sure if this is the correct wording. Here is some of my code for the x axis as an example.

```
  const getDefaultX = () =>
    d3
      .scaleUtc()
      // Min / Max dates
      .domain(d3.extent(data.chart, (d) => d.date))
      .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using [axis.ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis), such as adding this to the axis generator in your chart:

`ticks(5)` (Would set 5 ticks on the axis)